# Why is a locally closed subscheme defined in this way?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

I have started studying the theory of schemes using the book Algebraic Geometry I by Görtz and Wedhorn. 
There, they give the following definition of a locally closed subscheme:

> Let $X$ be a scheme. A (locally closed) subscheme of $X$ is a scheme $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ such that $Y\subseteq X$ is a locally closed subset and such that $Y$ is a closed  subscheme of the open subscheme $U\subseteq X$, where $U$ is the largest open subset of $X$ which contains $Y$ and in which $Y$ is closed (i.e., $U$ is the complement of $\overline{Y}\setminus Y$). We then have a natural morphism of schemes $Y\to X$.

My question is the following: why do they take explicitly *the largest possible* $U$? This seems unnatural to me. Does it make a difference if one takes any open subset $V$ such that $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $V$? Is it not the same, after composing with the inclusion $V\to U$?

I think that this probably has some meaning, so there must be some subtle point which I am missing. I have looked it up in other books and, for example, in EGA I the definition is essentially the same. In contrast, the book by Bosch defines a locally closed subscheme as a closed subscheme of an open subscheme (*any*, not necessarily the largest possible).

Comment: Can you give the page number in Görtz and Wedhorn where this notion is defined? Thanks!

Comment: It is definition 3.43 on page 85.

Comment: There is no difference. I think this is just convention.

Comment: You can prove that the maximality of $U$ is unuseful!

Comment: So it seems by your comments that I was just reading too much into this, right? Thanks!

Comment: @Gispsan Yes. One has to be worried sometimes also about whether you can reverse it (i.e. whether open embedding followed by closed embedding or the opposite) but this is also, under reasonable hypotheses (I think just locally Noetherian?), also a non-issue.